# adding attribute using knockout js with dynamic string value

Tags: html, knockout.js

I am working on dynamically creating the tiles like UI for showing the metrics. i want to show some color dynamically based on the id. i need to append  "_flag" with the dynamic value(symptom.symId = S1). my code is given below.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: {data:symptomArray , as: 'symptom'}">
<div data-bind="attr:{ id : symptom.symId}"> </div> 
</div>
```

Please help me

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Where do you want to append this `_flag`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you want to do:

```
attr: { id: sympton.symId + '_flag' }
```

or if `symId` is observable, then:

```
attr: { id: sympton.symId() + '_flag' }
```